# Multiple Columns to calculate new column using equation

Tags: r

I'm a fairly new R user -- trying to teach myself based on forums, videos, and trial+error. I have a very large dataset and would like to calculate number of members in the household who are considered children ( aged under 18). I have a column for number of household members, as well as 11 columns for each household member's age. My initial thought would be to select those who are under 18 and subtract from total household members. I've tried a few different lines of code unsuccessfully and I'm not sure how best to go about executing this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLDja.png)

Comment: Copying this from the header on the page for [r] questions: "Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead." Also read the highly  voted question: "how to make a great reproducible example in R". Putting in the code you have tried is usually a good idea. It let's people evaluate where they should pitch their answers.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you all ^^ for the tips, I apologize for not adding the code in -- next time I will be sure to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  I'm using something called a datastep from the libr package.

First, here is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(num_hhmem = c(6, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 8, NA),
                 ChildAge = c(9, 8, 10, 10, 9, NA, 8, NA),
                 hhm2_Age = c(36, 44, 52, 40, 33, NA, 37, NA),
                 hhm3_Age = c(34, 16, 53, 15, 15, NA, 39, NA),
                 hhm4_Age = c(15, 10, 92, 17, 11, NA, NA, NA),
                 hhm5_Age = c(7, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, 10, NA),
                 hhm6_Age = c(11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA),
                 hhm7_Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 68, NA),
                 hhm8_Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 78, NA),
                 hhm9_Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Then I set up the datastep with an array for the columns you want to iterate.  Also I also set up a childCount variable with the value of 0 to start with.  The datastep will loop through the dataframe row by row.  So then you just iterate through the array and add any children to the childCount variable.

```
library(libr)

res <- datastep(df, 
                arrays = list(ages = dsarray("ChildAge", "hhm2_Age", "hhm3_Age",
                                             "hhm4_Age", "hhm5_Age", "hhm6_Age",
                                             "hhm7_Age", "hhm8_Age", "hhm9_Age")),
                calculate = { childCount <- 0 },
                drop = "age",
                {
                  
                  for(age in ages) {

                    if (!is.na(ages[age])) {
                      if (ages[age] < 18)
                        childCount <- childCount + 1
                    
                    }
                  }
                  
                })
```

Here are the results:

```
res
#   num_hhmem ChildAge hhm2_Age hhm3_Age hhm4_Age hhm5_Age hhm6_Age hhm7_Age hhm8_Age hhm9_Age childCount
# 1         6        9       36       34       15        7       11       NA       NA       NA          4
# 2         4        8       44       16       10       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA          3
# 3         4       10       52       53       92       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA          1
# 4         5       10       40       15       17       20       NA       NA       NA       NA          3
# 5         4        9       33       15       11       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA          3
# 6        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA          0
# 7         8        8       37       39       NA       10        6       68       78       NA          3
# 8        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA          0
```

Comment: David, thank you so much for formatting the data for me, I apologize that I didn't realize to do that myself. Your solution worked perfectly and you worded it in a way that I could understand-- I appreciate you!!

Comment: Hi David, I had a question about this code if you're able to answer. This code is working great, but the column doesn't stay in my df. So I can't manipulate it into different code, if that makes sense. I see it in my dataframe, but it the column says "object 'childCount' not found" when i try to plug it in for other  code. Do you know how i could fix that?

Comment: The code above is putting it in a new data frame called "res'.  If you want it back in the original dataframe, replace "res" with "df" in the code above.  Or do "df <- res" after the datastep is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another potential solution using tidyverse functions and the data formatted by @David J. Bosak:

```
df1 <- data.frame(num_hhmem = c(6, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 8, NA),
                  ChildAge = c(9, 8, 10, 10, 9, NA, 8, NA),
                  hhm2_Age = c(36, 44, 52, 40, 33, NA, 37, NA),
                  hhm3_Age = c(34, 16, 53, 15, 15, NA, 39, NA),
                  hhm4_Age = c(15, 10, 92, 17, 11, NA, NA, NA),
                  hhm5_Age = c(7, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, 10, NA),
                  hhm6_Age = c(11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA),
                  hhm7_Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 68, NA),
                  hhm8_Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 78, NA),
                  hhm9_Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

df2 <- df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(total_kids = rowSums(across(-c(num_hhmem), ~sum(.x <= 18, na.rm = TRUE))))
df2
#> # A tibble: 8 × 11
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   num_hhmem ChildAge hhm2_Age hhm3_Age hhm4_Age hhm5_Age hhm6_Age hhm7_Age hhm8_Age hhm9_Age total_kids
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>         <dbl>
#> 1         6        9       36       34       15        7       11       NA       NA NA                4
#> 2         4        8       44       16       10       NA       NA       NA       NA NA                3
#> 3         4       10       52       53       92       NA       NA       NA       NA NA                1
#> 4         5       10       40       15       17       20       NA       NA       NA NA                3
#> 5         4        9       33       15       11       NA       NA       NA       NA NA                3
#> 6        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA NA                0
#> 7         8        8       37       39       NA       10        6       68       78 NA                3
#> 8        NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA NA                0
```

Or, if you just want the counts in a dataframe on their own:

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  summarise(total_kids = rowSums(across(-c(num_hhmem), ~sum(.x <= 18, na.rm = TRUE))))
df3
#> # A tibble: 8 × 1
#>   total_kids
#>        <dbl>
#> 1          4
#> 2          3
#> 3          1
#> 4          3
#> 5          3
#> 6          0
#> 7          3
#> 8          0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jared, I really appreciate your help!!